# How do you get a collection of named shapes in Visio VBA

Tags: vba, collections, shapes, visio, named

I need the get a user defined integer value from the shapes named "CovIBox" on the active page.

What is the correct method?

```vb
Private Function GetLastNumber() As Integer
    ''Need to get the last User Integer property of the shape "CovIBox"
    ''placed on the active page
    
    Dim oPage As Visio.Page
    Dim OColl As Collection
    Dim intShapeVal As Integer
    Dim IntHighest As Integer
    Dim Ival As Integer
    
    Set oPage = Application.ActiveWindow.Page
   
    Set OColl = oPage.Shapes.Name("CovIBox")    <----This where it fails

    Ival = 0
    For Each Shape In vsoCollection
        Ival = Shape.CellsU("Prop.InterfaceNo").value
        If Ival > IntHighest Then
            IntHighest = Ival
        End If
    Next
    
    Set OColl = Nothing
    Set oPage = Nothing
    
    GetLastNumber = IntHighest + 1
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set OColl = oPage.Shapes.Name("CovIBox)`

In Visio each shape have unique name. You mast iterate all shapes per page, check their master name and collect intrested shape to collection